# Convert object with similar keys into string

Tags: node.js, query-string

I am sending a query string inside a get request from my website to node application, I am then using node's inbuilt query string module to expand it to an object but it gets stuck when an array `optional` gets converted to a string. The array gets converted like this

```js
{
  'optional[0]': '440550777912819712',
  'optional[1]': '442805547096342529',
  'optional[2]': '442805442566160394',
}
```

but I am wondering how I could use query string to convert it to this

```js
{  optional: [
                '440550777912819712',
                '442805547096342529',
                '442805442566160394'
              ]
}
```

the relevant part of the query string is this

```
optional%5B0%5D=440550777912819712&optional%5B1%5D=442805547096342529&optional%5B2%5D=442805442566160394
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some loop that will preserve the value and consolidate this with the same key. Something like

```
  function renderOption() {
    return props.data
      ? props.data.map((dataDescription, key) => {
          return <option key={key}>{dataDescription[props.field]}</option>;
        })
      : '';
  }
```

or something like this: https://medium.com/@edisondevadoss/javascript-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key-afc85c35d07e
once you are using the same key.